# How to insert a params in Fetch GET request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, restful-url

I created a simple Flask's jsonify that I do not sure if I can call it as API, but I receive a JSON Object.

```
@app.route('/searchData/<int:id>',methods=["GET"])
def searchData(id):
    return jsonify(searchData(id))
```

Now using Fetch function, I cant pass the arg `<int:id>`, I don't if I can add params to Header in Flask to accepted the argument.

```
  async fetch(id){      
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:5000/searchData/",
        {
          method:"GET"
        }
    );
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
  }
```

Comment: Type it after searchData/!

Comment: sorry, can you explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `"` to back ticks to make it a string literal and add it with interpolation.

```
async fetch(id){      
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/searchData/${id}`,
        {
          method:"GET"
        }
    );
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
  }
```

Using this style of interpolation makes it so much easier to read when you have a few params

Comment: Thank you for answering, I receive a error in VUE.JS saying `error  'id' is defined but never used`

Comment: Yeah that would of been talking about the `fetch(id)` method you created. With that usage in the URL it should suffice Vue and clear that error

Comment: I did the way you explained, but error indicates `async fetch(id){ ` never used

Comment: This may not work but try changing the `async fetch(id){` name to `fetchDataById(id)` or anything else you like the look of. Just curious if its reading itself wrong because if the same names

Comment: I got to fix it "concatenating" url + id like  `'http://localhost:5000/searchData/'+id` Thank you for helping me @Floyd